# How to embed font into PDF file displayed in UIWebview?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, pdf, uiwebview

I am opening a pdf file downloaded from server into UIWebview. However, the pdf opens correctly into the web view, but there is an error displayed on console:

```
LLALCK+MyriadPro-SemiboldIt: FT_Select_Charmap failed: error 6
```

After some r&d I found that this issue is related to fonts.

I would like to know how to embed fonts within the pdf, so that the above error is eliminated. I tried installing font.otf file on Mac and tried to run pdf display on simulator, but it still gives same error.

Following is the code which I use to display pdf in uiwebview:

```
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

[webView
 loadData:data
 MIMEType:@"application/pdf"
 textEncodingName:@"UTF-8"
 baseURL:nil];
```

Please help.

Badly stuck!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you using to create the PDF?

Comment: please see my edited question, I have added code there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your PDF references a font which the device does not have. You could try adding this font to your bundle, but this can be problematic in several key areas.First, I am not sure WebView can read custom fonts for the purpose of PDFs; but more importantly, second, you likely do not have a license to embed that font in your application.

I would suggest tackling this problem from a different perspective. How is your PDF created on the server? Either use a safe font in your PDF (see a full list of iOS fonts [here](http://iosfonts.com/)), or use the font embedding feature of PDF and use that. Fonts usually come with a more relaxed license when embedding certain glyph in PDFs.